# How avoid jump line disappear when concat string [BASH]

Tags: linux, bash

I want to list all urls contain in all file of my project.

First function `find_url_in_file`, work well --> I have this list

```
https://www.example.com/en/docs/console/my-project/how-to/add-resources-project
https://www.example.com/en/docs/console/my-project/how-to/generate-api-key
https://www.example.com/en/docs/console/my-project/how-to/delete-a-project
https://www.example.com/en/docs/console/my-project/how-to/join-an-organization
```

Then with second function `find_all_url_in_file`, when it concat it remove all line jump :

```
https://www.example.com/en/docs/console/my-project/how-to/add-resources-projecthttps://www.example.com/en/docs/console/my-project/how-to/generate-api-keyhttps://www.example.com/en/docs/console/my-project/how-to/delete-a-projecthttps://www.example.com/en/docs/console/my-project/how-to/join-an-organization
```

I want to keep this line break to have a simple clean nice list. How could I do?
(maybe it's a better idea to use a temp file ?)

```
all_mdx_file=$(find_all_mdx)

find_url_in_file(){
    local file="${1}"
    local url_list=""
    grep -Eo '(http|https)://www.xxxxxx.com[^ )>"]+' $file || : | \
    while IFS= read -r url; do 
        url_list+="$url"
    done
    echo "$url_list"
}

find_all_url_in_file(){
    local file="${1}"
    local list_url=""
    while IFS= read -r mdx; do 
        # echo "mdx read : $mdx"
        url_in_this_file=$(find_url_in_file $mdx )
        list_url+="$url_in_this_file "
    done <<< "$file"
}

find_all_url_in_file "$all_mdx_file"
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please [edit] and provide [mcve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367019/10765659). For now the example is not complete: what is `find_all_mdx`? what is the input data? You should also make clear what exact command(s) give you the output, i.e. the "list" and the "wrong" output. Note the second function does not print anything (right?), so how *exactly* do you get the "wrong" output? What exact output do you want to get? Put yourself in our shoes. We don't have your files, functions or ideas. We only know your setup by what you tell us. So help us replicate the problem.

Comment: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03: `...with the standard output of the command, removing sequences of one or more <newline> characters at the end of the substitution.`

Comment: So either add `list_url+=$'\n'` in the loop, or perhaps even better: use an array.

Comment: @TomYan, thanks for the link with explanation. 
After thinking about it, it's stupid to use string --> I should use array